# phpmyadmin bummer

Tags: sql, mysql, phpmyadmin

I think i did some nasty crap today...

I deleted the user (admin root) in phpmyadmin (XAMPP)
now I can't create new users.

Any idea how to fix, or should I just try re-install the hole XAMPP packet :-/
I use Leopard iMac.

/Willy

Comment: I don't know, which text editor there is, or where XAMPP locates its files on a Mac, but chances are, that it is a 1 minute task to recreate the admin user. If you don't get an answer here, look at the phpmyadmin documentation over at their website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a method for [resetting permissions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-unix) in the MySQL manual.  It deals with resetting the root password rather than recreating the root account, however I think you should be able to modify the method to re-insert the root account without any trouble.

Following the steps listed there (either method), if you change step 3 to insert a new account (fields might vary, this worked for my particular install):

```
INSERT INTO user VALUES('localhost','root',PASSWORD('some_pass'),'Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y');
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

You should be able to take it from there and get the permissions back up to snuff.

Comment: Hey... 

error when adding the new user. 

ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need the RELOAD privilege for this operation

To RELOAD privilege I wrote that I had to be an super user/ admin :-/ 

any ideas ?

Comment: The mysql.user table has many columns dealing with privileges... for the root user they should probably all be set to 'Y'.  I updated the query in my answer, try that one.  If it's the FLUSH PRIVILEGES call that's causing the error, then I believe restarting the MySQL Server will have the same effect.

Comment: Maybe I do something wrong, I can't figueout. But seems like i get the same error again :S 

# 1
mysql> INSERT INTO user VALUES('localhost','root',PASSWORD('pass'),'Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y'); FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need the RELOAD privilege for this operation

# 2 
mysql> INSERT INTO user VALUES('localhost','root',PASSWORD(''),'Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y');

ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected

does anything rings for you ? :-)

Comment: Try starting your mysql session using `mysql -u root` instead of just `mysql`.  There's a forum post here that describes the exact same process but it might be easier to follow:  http://forums.fedoraforum.org/archive/index.php/t-168046.html

Comment: @zombat I really appreciate you help, Thank you very much. I will take a look at the link.